# cURL connecting to the localhost when given a bad URL

Tags: php, http, curl

I am going through a list of user supplied URLs to see which ones do not get a valid HTTP response code from the server when they are requested. During QA we found that links looking like `http://broken` were not being flagged as invalid.

We have a php script that uses cURL to get the http headers and parses out the response code.  We do allow for redirects and follow them using final response code returned if there are a number of redirects.  One test was saying that a request to `http://broken` returns a 200.  Clearly not what I want.  That improperly formatted url should generate a 404 response, I would think.

I pulled out the code into a small test harness:

```
<?php
util_url_get_response_code("http://broken", true);

function util_url_get_response_code ($url, $follow_redirect = false) {
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    if ($follow_redirect) { curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); }

    $data = curl_exec( $handle );
    $err = curl_error($handle);
    curl_close( $handle );
    print_r($data);
}
?>
```

When that test code is run, the headers printed look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2013 17:39:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Location: http://www.nitrc.org/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2013 17:39:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=oorncckdt198341u4lccpoai12; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Looking at the first header, it appears that cURL contacted the www.nitrc.org server...which is our web site URL.  NITRC is configured to redirect unknown URLs to the home page, so we end up getting a 200 OK response header.

So, what can I do to get cURL to look at `http://broken` and return a 404 error the same way a browser would?

(Note that I can't turn off redirect processing because it is part of the requirements to follow any valid redirect!)

Comment: You probably have some broken network appliance on your network messing with DNS.  (Malware, captive portal software, "smart" DNS filtering, etc.)  This has nothing to do with your code or cURL.

Comment: you can try to connect any whois service and you can understand is this server reachable or not...

Comment: This `smart` filtering should at least give a 404...but I guess you could try disabling this. Contact the network admin if you're not one already.

Comment: I don't think it is malware because valid domains return the expected responses.  But is does seem to behave strangely when the domain is not valid. I will talk to the network admin to see if there is a HTTP proxy or some other net oddity that might be responsible for the odd results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Brad for pointing me in the right direction to find this:

Our test server had both a wildcard *.nitrc.org defined in DNS and also a "search nitrc.org" directive in resolve.conf.  Therefore, every domain that wasn't valid would be prepended to nitrc.org and would then match our wildcard dns.